# Why did my bar buttons disappear? And my title didn't change? And a non-existent tableview appears?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uistoryboard, magicalrecord

I'm making a simple little iOS app incorporating MagicalRecord and Core Data. But I'm baffled by the discrepancies between the storyboard and the app as presented. My two bar buttons (Status and +) do not appear as expected. And regardless of what I type in the title for the view, it always reads "Home" (which was the original text). Also, I originally had a tableview but removed it. Nevertheless, it still appears, slightly askew, as shown in the accompanying screenshot.

I'll mention one other possible clue. I don't understand why it is there, nor do I understand how it could be causing this problem. In fact I plan to make it a separate question. I mention it here only because it is a mystery that a more experienced developer may recognize as suspect. Here it is, from the console:

```
2014-01-01 22:37:50.691 WMLG1[32260:a0b] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ImageToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'image' on entity 'Image'
2014-01-01 22:37:50.693 WMLG1[32260:a0b] CoreData: warning: no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ImageToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'thumbnailImage' on entity 'Recipe'
2014-01-01 22:37:50.724 WMLG1[32260:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x2f30ac) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2014-01-01 22:37:50.724 WMLG1[32260:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x2f30ac) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8a47b60>
2014-01-01 22:37:50.726 WMLG1[32260:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x2f30ac) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8a481b0>
2014-01-01 22:37:50.727 WMLG1[32260:a0b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x2f30ac) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8a481b0>*
```

The reason this is mysterious to me is that I have no entities called "Image" or "Recipe" in my model.

I'm pretty green, so anything is possible, although I was being really careful and felt I had a good grasp on the code (although I believe there may be some redundancy). Can someone please point out what I've done wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the relevant code from the HomeViewController:

```
//
//  HomeViewController.m
//  WMLG1
//
//  Created by Tim Jones on 1/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 TDJ. All rights reserved.
//


#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "ListActivity.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()
{
    NSFetchedResultsController * frc;
}

@end

@implementation HomeViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark Table View stuff


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:NO];
    return [[frc sections ]count];
}

- (NSInteger)sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)sectionIndex
{
    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:NO];
    return [frc sectionForSectionIndexTitle:@"category" atIndex:sectionIndex];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSInteger count = 0;
    NSInteger realNumberOfSections = [frc.sections count];
    if (section < realNumberOfSections)
    {
        // fetchedResultsController has this section
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [frc.sections objectAtIndex:section];
        count = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }
    else
    {
        // section not present in fetchedResultsController
        count = 0; // for empty section, or 1 if you want to show a "no objects" cell.
    }
    return count;}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:NO];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    // Check if a reusable cell object was dequeued
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Populate the cell with the appropriate name based on the indexPath
    cell.textLabel.text = [frc.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath];

    return cell;
}


#pragma mark Table View Delegate stuff

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}

@end
```

Comment: make sure you are assingn correct **viewcontroller name** in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Chancy! Not sure how you did it, but it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: @TimJones haha, you can check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to view how to do some formattings.

Comment: @Viruss--i just checked and both of my view controllers are assigned the the correct custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the app from the simulator by selecting "Hardware" from the bar at the top of screen and then "Home". Click and hold down on your app icon until a little "X" appears then click it to delete the app. In Xcode go to "Product" at the top and click "Clean". Then try running the app on the simulator again.

Is the Home View Controller your Initial View Controller?

You implemented UITableView control methods in your Home View Controller but asked about a UITableView showing up. Is that controller supposed to be a UITableViewController or is it simply a delegate?

Comment: @mike--I'll follow your suggestions (in the morning--I'm done for the night), but i've actually already tried both the things you recommend. Sorry, i should have mentioned that. Also, yes, the HomeViewController is my table view delegate. I'll report back in the morning. Thanks!

Comment: OK, things seem to be running properly, thanks to @Mike's suggestions. As mentioned, I had tried both fixes previously, but this morning they worked. I still had to delete and replace my nav controller for the next screen in order to get my nav bar buttons to show up. I don't remember Xcode/simulator doing this kind of thing to me before. Many thanks! Would vote up the answer, but don't have the rep. :(

Comment: Great, glad to hear its fixed. Its very rare that I have this type of issue, I'm not sure what causes it. You can accept the answer so the question is considered solved. :)

Comment: Done, @Mike, and thanks again! Look for me again--I'm an enthusiastic nooby with more questions than answers. :)